# ROW_NUMBER() Based on Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data:

```
test_date
2018-07-01
2018-07-02
...
2019-06-30
2019-07-01
2019-07-02
...
2020-06-30
2020-07-01
```

I want to increment a `row_number` value every time `right(test_date,5) = '07-01'` so that my final result looks like this:

```
test_date    row_num
2018-07-01         1
2018-07-02         1
...                1
2019-06-30         1
2019-07-01         2
2019-07-02         2
...                2
2020-06-30         2
2020-07-01         3
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY CASE WHEN RIGHT(a.[test_date],5) = '07-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ORDER BY a.[test_date]
) AS [test2]
```

But that did not work out for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`datepart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to identify the correct date, and then add 1 to a sum every time it changes (assuming there will never be more than 1 row per date).

```
declare @Test table (test_date date);

insert into @Test (test_date)
values
('2018-07-01'),
('2018-07-02'),
('2019-06-30'),
('2019-07-01'),
('2019-07-02'),
('2020-06-30'),
('2020-07-01');

select *
  , sum(case when datepart(month,test_date) = 7 and datepart(day,test_date) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by test_date asc) row_num
from @Test
order by test_date asc;
```

Returns:

| test_date | row_num |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-07-01 | 1 |
| 2018-07-02 | 1 |
| 2019-06-30 | 1 |
| 2019-07-01 | 2 |
| 2019-07-02 | 2 |
| 2020-06-30 | 2 |
| 2020-07-01 | 3 |

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with `DENSE_RANK()` window function if you subtract 6 months from your dates:

```
SELECT test_date,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(DATEADD(month, -6, test_date))) row_num
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a33fec6e8c77673d299ac9e60f56baf0).
Results:

```
test_date  | row_num
---------- | -------
2018-07-01 |       1
2018-07-02 |       1
2019-06-30 |       1
2019-07-01 |       2
2019-07-02 |       2
2020-06-30 |       2
2020-07-01 |       3
```

Answer (score 0):

build a running total based on month=7 and day=2

```
 declare @Test table (mykey int,test_date date);

 insert into @Test (mykey,test_date)
 values
  (1,'2018-07-01'),
 (2,'2018-07-02'),
 (3,'2019-06-30'),
 (4,'2019-07-01'),
 (5,'2019-07-02'),
 (6,'2020-06-30'),
 (7,'2020-07-01');

 select mykey,test_date, 
 sum(case when DatePart(Month,test_date)=7 and DatePart(Day,test_date)=2 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by mykey) RunningTotal from @Test
 order by mykey
```